# Access name of chosen directory in python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make my python program more accessible with a minimal GUI with Tkinter grid.

I've created a class that creates a button that asks for a directory to be chosen. This works as it should. However, I want the path of the directory to be mirrored in a row below the button.

```
class dir_choice:
  def __init__(self, master, text, prow, pcol):
    self.dir_button = Button(master, text = text, command = self.askdir)
    self.dir_button.grid(row = prow, column = pcol)

    self.feedb = Label(master, text = "text")
    self.feedb.grid(row = prow+1, column = pcol)

  def askdir(self):
    name = askdirectory() #from tkFileDialog
    return name
```

In use:

```
dir1 = dir_choice(root, "FOLDER 1", 3, 2)
```

Instead of `text = "text"` I want to have something like `"C:/user/A/B/C"` to be shown below the button if that directory is chosen.

I think I am not correct assuming that this is in the `name` variable or if it is, I would need to define it differently. So my question is how I can access the value of the `askdirectory()` function and how I can push that value to the `feedb` label.

Comment: Quick note. `self.dir_button` and `self.feedb` are None by definition. The reason is that `grid` returns None. Don't chain grid like this. Call it in e separate line, i.e. `self.dir_button.grid(...)`.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks. I changed this in my code and edited it. Any idea on my directory value problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was probably just a copy-paste error, but the indentation is incorrect.

[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style calls for, among other things, classes to be named with CamelCase. It won't make your code run any faster, but readability counts.

Avoid chaining your geometry management methods. If you chain your geometry methods (e.g. `grid()`) onto the widget creation, you end up saving those methods' return value, which is always `None`, so `self.dir_button` and `self.feedb` are both just `None`. Instead, put the geometry management method on a separate line.

To change a widget's properties, simply `configure()` it (or `config()` for short). `askdirectory()` returns a string, so you can use it directly or save it to something like `self.directory_name`. It's not useful to `return` it anywhere because the function was called by a `Button` and the `Button` can't do anything with returned values.

```
class DirChoice:
    def __init__(self, master, text, prow, pcol):
        self.dir_button = Button(master, text = text, command = self.askdir)
        self.dir_button.grid(row = prow, column = pcol)
        self.feedb = Label(master, text = "text")
        self.feedb.grid(row = prow+1, column = pcol)
    def askdir(self):
        self.feedb.config(text= askdirectory()) #from tkFileDialog
```